# Making scrollable view when changed to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

How can I make a view scrollable when changed to landscape mode? e.g. I have an app in portrait mode, lots of information involved. I hape preset all struts and springs, but I still need some space in the bottom, so I was thinking enabling scrolling function, but how could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll is enabled when the content size is bigger than the frame of the scroll. Try the following:

```
myScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(100.0f,200.0f);
myScroll.frame=CGRect(0.0f,0.0f,100.0f,100.0f);
```

This will make you scroll vertically, because the height of the content size is bigger than the height of the frame. While this would make you scroll horizontally:

```
myScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(100.0f,200.0f);
myScroll.frame=CGRect(0.0f,0.0f,200.0f,200.0f);
```

Either way, you when your screen rotates, you should handle your logic according that what I explain.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't really see how this helps me. What kind of class is myScroll, should I implement this code to some method which handles rotation?

Comment: It's a UIScrollView. The above explanation above was to help you understand the scrolling.

Comment: Well, my view isn't really UIScrollView. Isn't there any other way?